# How to insert a backslash in a string using regex or string functions to extract substrings after \ in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, split, substring, slice, backslash

I have the following strings:

```
school\boy
school\class
school\playground
school\teacher
school\subject
```

I want to extract the substring after the \ i.e., `boy`, `class`, `playground`, `teacher`, `subject`. Also, `school` remains a constant substring for all strings.

**I know the solution is to add in an extra backslash** like `school\\boy`, `school\\teacher` etc. since it's treating `\b`,`\t` as one special character, but the above data is coming from the `back-end` service so the solution to add the extra backslash manually for every string is not feasible.

My question is how can I insert this extra \ backslash through string functions or regex and extract the substrings after the \?

I tried doing this:

```
var str = "school\boy";
var newstr = str.slice(0,6) + '\\' + str.slice(6); \\ newstr = school\\boy
console.log(newstr.split('\\\\')[1]);
```

but it gives `undefined`. If I do a split by a single backslash, it gives output as `\boy` which is incorrect. I don't understand why the `split` doesn't work. It's still treating `\b` as a special character even after adding the extra \ after character `'l'` in the string.

Comment: Unfortunately, as soon as JS gets the strings it turns `\b` into a special character - I think you'd need a label function. (can't remember off the top of my head)

Comment: *so the solution to add the extra backslash manually for every string is not feasible.* Not really, it's pretty trivial to escape all characters that need escaping

Comment: @CertainPerformance These strings are coming from a database and there are thousands of them so escaping every string will be time consuming

Comment: If your *actual code* is like `var str = "school\boy";` then you don't have any actual backslashes in the code, but if the data is being taken from, eg, a network request, if it has backslashes, it's formatted correctly already..?

Comment: " It's still treating \b as a special character even after adding the extra \ after character 'l' in the string." — The \ only exists in the source code. Adding a \ to the in-memory string doesn't change the source code from which the string was created in the past to stop the \ being treated as an escape.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes the actual code is `var str = "school\boy";` and you're probably right about the backslash not being there because if I print "\b", it's giving a weird character. I guess we see it as a \ but the computer doesn't understand that?

Comment: If that's the actual code, then whatever's generating the code is broken and should be fixed. Since this is from a database, it sounds like it's being generated dynamically, right?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes you're right. The above code works for all characters after the \ which don't have any meaning. But in case of characters like \b or \n or \t etc., this code doesn't work and I am unable to extract the substring. So you're suggesting that a fix needs to be made at the back-end then?

Comment: Is the code being generated dynamically? If so, that code generator is broken, and should be fixed. (though, ideally, you wouldn't be *writing* dynamic JS like that anyway, better to use something like JSON)

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes the code's generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your back-end is generating the JavaScript code (with only one backslash). **The best thing to do is to reconfigure your back-end.**

You can also use `fetch()` to perform a `GET` request to obtain the string, which won't need escaping.

However, if for some reason, you can't do that, you can use `String.raw()`:

```js
const str = String.raw `school\boy`; // Yes, without parenthesis.
console.log(str.split("\\")[1])
```

But if you use `String.raw()`, make sure there's something after the backslhash, as `` \` `` will **not** terminate the string!

Comment: This works like a charm. But, yes the long-term solution is to fix the way this code is generated. Thanks!